# Show by double counting that $ 3 {n \choose 4} + 3{n\choose 3} = {{n \choose 2} \choose 2}$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

${{n \choose 2} \choose 2}=3 {n \choose 4} + 3{n\choose 3}$
It's easy to show this by expanding into factorials but I can't find an argument for the combinatorial proof.

Comment: Hint: consider how you can choose unordered pairs of 'unordered pairs of balls' from among $n$ labeled balls. The two pairs can't be _identical_ - but they can overlap (e.g., $\langle 1,2\rangle$ and $\langle 1,3\rangle$). Find a mapping from pairs of non-overlapping pairs to unordered sets of four balls, and a mapping from pairs of overlapping pairs to unordered sets of three balls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are ${n\choose 2}$ subset which has 2 element from set n-element.

There are ${{n\choose 2} \choose 2}$ way to choose 2 2-element subsets from ${n\choose 2}$ such subsets.

It means that we choose 2 subset $\{a,b\}$ and $\{c,d\}$. Note that it has two cases two sets have one common element or two set are disjoint.

On the other hand, there are ${n\choose 4}$ way to choose 4 element from n-element set and there are 3 way to divide 4 element to two distinct sets.

There are ${n\choose 3}$ way to choose 3 element from n-element set and there are 3 way to divide 3 element to two set which has one common element.

Comment: The first "distinct" should be replaced by "disjoint".

Comment: Done! Sorry for typo.